# Time-out 504 Gateway Time-out nginx in wordpress-php-fpm

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, kubernetes

I want to setup WordPress PHP-fpm in Kubernetes, so I already setup that but there is some problem that currently I am facing with Nginx proxy, so when I am trying to install the woo-commerce plugin then it gives the error of

Installation failed: 504 Gateway Time-out 504 Gateway Time-out nginx padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -> < ! - padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page ->

I don't know what's going wrong on proxy I already set the max value for proxy_read_timeout 100. but then also it will not work. I tried so many proxy time-out values but it didn't work, so here is my Nginx proxy config 

wordpress.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
 
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
 
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/hakase-access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/hakase-error.log;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache phpcache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 60m;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
        fastcgi_cache_lock on;
        add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout updating invalid_header http_500 http_503;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:100m max_size=10g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: It's your local env or On prem? This issue occured after you have installed `woo-commerce plugin` and before that, it worked properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one working for me

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
}
```

You must be running the two containers inside the single pod you can debug the logs of ingress and nginx of WordPress to check more details.

you can use this github as reference : https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx

Also, check the blog to understand more :  https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx-73cb4f9aef02