# Nginx - Upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I have a setup with Ubuntu 20.04, Nginx.
I have a wordpress site, which I built an API endpoint.

This API endpoint is quite large, which is possibly the reason why I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway.  Other API endpoints which is smaller are working fine on the same server.

I am terribly bad with system administration, and desperately looking for assistance here.

Here is what my nginx config looks like for the site.
I have tried everything from proxy buffers, to fastcgi.
But, i am still receiving the same error messages in the logs regarding upstream.

```
server {
        server_name test.com;

        client_max_body_size 100M;

        proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
        proxy_buffers 4 512k;
        proxy_buffer_size  256k;

        location / {
                root /var/www/test/wordpress;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         }
}
```

Would anybody have a clue whats going on? Is the fastcgi buffer not taking in effect?

Comment: try this (and search first): https://stackoverflow.com/a/66362380/973254